# What to use for a Palm Detection/Scanning feature in Flutter

Tags: android, ios, mobile, flutter, dart

I want to create a feature for Palm Lines recognition/scanning, would prefer to get this app done using Flutter SDK. Im already a bit familiar with flutter. Any recommendations how to get this feature started ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase ML kit to achieve this feature.
Flutter SDK does not contains any kind of image processing features.

Comment: can you share the link of any example or something?